# Umount when umount -lf doesn't work

Tags: server, nfs, umount, backuppc

I'm trying to troubleshoot our NAS, and frankly, I'm getting sick of it, every time I try and unmount the connection on our server (Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS fully updated) it simply refuses to unmount the NFS share.

`/proc/mounts`:

```
10.43.1.134:/c/Servers /mnt/backups rw,noatime,vers=3,rsize=131072,wsize=131072,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,mountaddr=10.43.1.134,mountvers=3,mountport=3072,mountproto=udp,local_lock=none,addr=10.43.1.134 0 0
```

Every time I issue `sudo umount -lf /mnt/backups` it simply hangs, and destroys another SSH session. So I've taken to running that with &.

Which according to the docs is *really not supposed to happen*.

Certain processes (backupPC) which were writing to that share are still running, and `kill -9` won't stop them... not sure why, that seems illogical.

It's locking my IO basically..

How do I stop them and umount it without resorting to a reboot?

Comment: ok, so still further googling reveals it might be the "hard" option, which apparently means it keeps trying indefinitely, I'll try remounting and see if that fixes it. http://serverfault.com/a/597322/35383

Answer (score 1):

To fix it, I just had to issue

```
sudo mount -o remount,soft 10.43.1.134:/c/Servers /mnt/backups
```

All fixed. Everything umounted, all the errant processes received the notification that they were unwanted, load average immediately dropped back to sane levels... I'm only ever using "soft" in future again!

*I actually thought you needed that to use hard-links on the mount point :-(*

Comment: @Zanna the "it was hard" comment was because the mount was in "hard" mode.. Remounting in "soft" mode instead fixed the issue. But thanks for formatting it.